# oracle 11g impdp returns invalid operation and object was not found

Tags: oracle, database-table, impdp, expdp, oracle-dump

I wanted to transfer an oracle table between two users using `expdp` and `impdp` commands.

First of all, I created a directory and granted proper privileges to source and destination users:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY TEST_DIR AS '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/temp_dirs';
Directory created.
SQL> GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY test_dir TO SOURCE_USER;
Grant succeeded.
SQL> GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY test_dir TO DEST_USER;
Grant succeeded.
SQL> commit;
```

This is my `expdp` command and it's output:

```
oracle@lab-57:~$ expdp SOURCE_USER/SOURCE_USER tables=tbl_user directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=users.dmp logfile=exp_users.log 

Export: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue Jul 24 16:18:27 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
Starting "SOURCE_USER"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01":  SOURCE_USER/******** tables=tbl_user directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=users.dmp logfile=exp_users.log 
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 64 KB
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type TABLE_EXPORT/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
. . exported "SOURCE_USER"."TBL_USER"                        8.085 KB       2 rows
Master table "SOURCE_USER"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for SOURCE_USER.SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01 is:
  /u01/app/oracle/oradata/temp_dirs/users.dmp
Job "SOURCE_USER"."SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01" successfully completed at 16:18:38
```

This implies the export operation was done successfully.

Then I tried to import it using `impdp` as following:

```
oracle@lab-57:~$ impdp DEST_USER/DEST_USER tables=TBL_USER directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=users.dmp logfile=imp_users.log

Import: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue Jul 24 17:26:58 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39166: Object DEST_USER.TBL_USER was not found.
```

I also tried `tables=DEST_USER.TBL_USER` and `content=data_only`; both returned same error.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-619809A6-1966-42D6-9ACC-A3E0ADC36523.htm#SUTIL927

Answer (score 0):

As you're exporting as `SOURCE_USER` and importing as `DEST_USER`, the `REMAP_SCHEMA` parameter might help. (I'll split the command into several rows for easier reading)

```
impdp DEST_USER/DEST_USER tables=TBL_USER directory=TEST_DIR 
dumpfile=users.dmp logfile=imp_users.log
remap_schema=source_user:dest_user             --> this
```

If you're on 11.2, you might hit a bug which won't allow you to do that (see My Oracle Support for more info). In that case, you can still perform import, but you'll have to omit the `TABLES` parameter, i.e.

```
                          TABLES was in this gap
                                 |
impdp DEST_USER/DEST_USER        v       directory=TEST_DIR 
dumpfile=users.dmp logfile=imp_users.log
remap_schema=source_user:dest_user
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer :

Create import : keep the dump ready.

Two option to restore the dump , consider complete dump or specific table.

For table specific :- Table name = MONTHS_DAY

`impdp DBA_USER/DBA_Password tables = SOURCE_SCHEMA.MONTHS_DAY directory=AKSHAY_SPM_EDIR dumpfile=MONTHS_DAY.dmp logfile=impdpMONTHS_DAY.log remap_schema = SOURCE_SCHEMA:DESTINATION_SCHEMA`

For complete import :

`impdp DBA_USER/DBA_Password directory = AKSHAY_SPM_EDIR dumpfile=MONTHS_DAY.dmp logfile=impdpMONTHS_DAY.log remap_schema = SOURCE_SCHEMA:DESTINATION_SCHEMA`

**Make sure, directory is accessible as dump is present there**